# saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile changing the character encoding to UTF-8

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to save the RDD with ISO-8859-1 charset encoded  using saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile to AWS S3 bucket
But its changing the character encoding to UTF-8 when its saved to S3 bucket.

Code snippet

```
val cell = “ MYCOST £25” //This is in UTF-8 character encoding .  
val charset: Charset = Charset.forName(“ISO-8859-1”)    
val cellData = cell.padTo(50, “ “).mkString   

val  iso-data = new String(cellData.getBytes(charset), charset) // here it converts the string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
```

But when I save the file using saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile then it changes to UTF-8 format. 
I think saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile TextOutputFormat automatically converting the file encoding to UTF-8. Is there a way I can save the content to S3 bucket with the same encoding (ISO-8859-1)

```
ds.rdd.map { record =>  
    val cellData = record.padTo(50, “ “).mkString  
    new String(cellData.getBytes(“ISO-8859-1”), “ISO-8859-1”)
 }.reduce { _ + _ }
    }.mapPartitions { iter =>
      val text = new Text()
      iter.map { item =>
        text.set(item)
        (NullWritable.get(), text)
      }
    }.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(“”s3://mybucket/“, classOf[NullWritable], classOf[BytesWritable], classOf[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, BytesWritable]])
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't got the correct answer but as a workaround, I am copying the file to HDFS and converting the file to ISO format using ICONV and saving back to S3 bucket. This is doing the job for me but it requires extra two steps in EMR cluster. 
I thought it might be useful to anyone who comes across the same problem